# wordpress insert and update query not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert and update data but it does not seems to work in wordpress . The database exist and when i try to insert it manually it works .

```
global $wpdb;
$db=$wpdb->prefix.'arete_woocommerce_sms_panel_settings';
$data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM {$db}");
    if (!empty( $data )) {
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_url",'value'=>$sms_provider_url),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_username_with_param",'value'=>$username),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_password_with_param",'value'=>$password),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_key_with_param",'value'=>$sms_api_key_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_sender_id_with_param",'value'=>$sms_api_sender_id_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->update("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_custom_with_param",'value'=>$sms_custom_values_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));  
    }
    else
    {
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_url",'value'=>$sms_provider_url),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_username_with_param",'value'=>$username),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_password_with_param",'value'=>$password),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_key_with_param",'value'=>$sms_api_key_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_sender_id_with_param",'value'=>$sms_api_sender_id_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));
                        $wpdb->insert("{$db}",array('type'=>"sms_provider_custom_with_param",'value'=>$sms_custom_values_with_parameter),array('%s','%s'));                     
    }
```

Comment: did you tried to print  $wpdb->last_query ;  and   $wpdb->last_error   , so that you can find th mysql error

Comment: 'sms_provider_sender_id_with_param' seems to be an number you should be using %d as a placeholder wherever it is used. Try this solution too after debugging.